# how can I create an automatic marking by javascript for my table

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a table and I need to bold it  I do not know how I can make it .
for example just like the code from week marking
The problem is, because time is always is different .The my problem because I do not know how to do it

Here is the table that I need to edit

```js
var days = 'sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday'.split(',');

document.getElementById( days[(new Date()).getDay()] ).className = 'bold';
```

```css
.bold {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
The example is how it will work

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();
var currentMinute = currentDate.getMinutes();
var minuteBin = currentMinute - (currentMinute % 15);
var idString = ""+currentHour+minuteBin;

console.log("Time =",currentHour,":",currentMinute,"bin =",minuteBin,"idString =",idString);

document.getElementById(idString).className = 'bold';
```

```css
.bold {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr id="2115">
        <td>21:45</td>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2130">
        <td>22:00</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2145">
        <td>22:15</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why dont you give a class to the `<td>` for which bold has to be applied and use CSS to make it bold.

Comment: The problem is I do not want to have everything bold only time anything is itself labeled

Comment: ok..but then you can give a class only for the `<td>` in which time is shown, if I understand your question correctly..

Comment: I posted as an example, as weekdays .The change automatically jedern day. and I want the same thing only with the times I stand in tabele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to iterate over the TD and add a class to bold the ones you want bold. Here is an example making use of jQuery but it is straight forward to do the same thing without jQuery (just a little more work):

```
var time = '18:55';

$('table td:nth-child(1)').each(function(index, td) {
    if ($(td).text() === time) {
        $(td).addClass('highlight-time');
    } else {
        $(td).removeClass('highlight-time');
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sah27uo6/2/

To set the TD bold for the current hour, you could do this:

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();

$('table td:nth-child(1)').each(function(index, td) {
    if ($(td).text().indexOf(hour) == 0) {
        $(td).addClass('highlight-time');
    } else {
        $(td).removeClass('highlight-time');
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sah27uo6/3/

Note that it is the current hour on the user's computer. If they are in a different time zone, there will be issues. So it becomes more complicated at that point.

Comment: The problem is I do not want to have everything bold only time anything is itself labeled

Comment: What does 'is itself labeled' mean?

Comment: yes you are right I want specific times to be bold .and the time is changed automatically .genau like the example with weekdays

Comment: I'm sorry my English is not really good. I need something that the table autmatik marked something wie.gethours () or .getminuts () something with this code.er must mark the time specified, for example, now it is  08: 45clock and he bold time 09:05

Comment: @TonTonii I updated an example to set the current hour bold. If you want more precision, it gets more complicated particularly with timezones. You'll want to pull in MomentJS or something similar and use a hidden attribute on the time that you can use to compare times.

Comment: Yes it is only in the EU, I have a use for. but I have problems because he always fixed 15 minutes. I post the question in the top vileicht they can help me edit the

Comment: that only works a small thing nor is it possible to not 21 +1 times more because the time is .as where it is used 1 hour earlier  many many many thanks